# Bash or Z shell terminal prompt with time and date

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, ps1

I am running Bash and Z shell (`zsh` executable) as my terminal environments.

My **main goal** is that I would like to add a timestamp onto all of my prompts...

Something along the lines of: *PS1_DATE="\D{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}"*

[This is the prompt from .bashrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZKxt.jpg).

[This is the prompt from .zshrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcJq5.jpg).

I also want my prompts to look the same. I would like it if both my prompts looked like my Z shell prompt (I like the colors).

Currently it’s a miracle that any of them look the way I want, since I don't have any idea what I'm doing, and since I Frankenstein'd my [.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) and [.zshrc](https://wiki.debian.org/Zsh#Configuration) files. And to any experienced person, they are probably painful to look at.

From what I can tell, I am using a *.dir_colors* file in both *rc* files and this is overriding the color settings, but they should only be for the “LS”, although I could be wrong.

#### Current *.bashrc* file:

```
#
# ~/.bashrc
#

[[ $- != *i* ]] && return

colors() {
    local fgc bgc vals seq0

    printf "Color escapes are %s\n" '\e[${value};...;${value}m'
    printf "Values 30..37 are \e[33mforeground colors\e[m\n"
    printf "Values 40..47 are \e[43mbackground colors\e[m\n"
    printf "Value  1 gives a  \e[1mbold-faced look\e[m\n\n"

    # foreground colors
    for fgc in {30..37}; do
        # background colors
        for bgc in {40..47}; do
            fgc=${fgc#37} # white
            bgc=${bgc#40} # black

            vals="${fgc:+$fgc;}${bgc}"
            vals=${vals%%;}

            seq0="${vals:+\e[${vals}m}"
            printf "  %-9s" "${seq0:-(default)}"
            printf " ${seq0}TEXT\e[m"
            printf " \e[${vals:+${vals+$vals;}}1mBOLD\e[m"
        done
        echo; echo
    done
}

[ -r /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ] && . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion

# Change the window title of X terminals
case ${TERM} in
    xterm*|rxvt*|Eterm*|aterm|kterm|gnome*|interix|konsole*)
        PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}:${PWD/#$HOME/\~}\007"'
        ;;
    screen*)
        PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033_${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}:${PWD/#$HOME/\~}\033\\"'
        ;;
esac

use_color=true

# Set colorful PS1 only on colorful terminals.
# dircolors --print-database uses its own built-in database
# instead of using /etc/DIR_COLORS.  Try to use the external file
# first to take advantage of user additions.  Use internal bash
# globbing instead of external grep binary.
safe_term=${TERM//[^[:alnum:]]/?}   # sanitize TERM
match_lhs=""
[[ -f ~/.dir_colors   ]] && match_lhs="${match_lhs}$(<~/.dir_colors)"
[[ -f /etc/DIR_COLORS ]] && match_lhs="${match_lhs}$(</etc/DIR_COLORS)"
[[ -z ${match_lhs}    ]] \
    && type -P dircolors >/dev/null \
    && match_lhs=$(dircolors --print-database)
[[ $'\n'${match_lhs} == *$'\n'"TERM "${safe_term}* ]] && use_color=true

if ${use_color} ; then
    # Enable colors for ls, etc.  Prefer ~/.dir_colors #64489
    if type -P dircolors >/dev/null ; then
        if [[ -f ~/.dir_colors ]] ; then
            eval $(dircolors -b ~/.dir_colors)
        elif [[ -f /etc/DIR_COLORS ]] ; then
            eval $(dircolors -b /etc/DIR_COLORS)
        fi
    fi

    if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]] ; then
        PS1='\[\033[01;31m\][\h\[\033[01;36m\] \W\[\033[01;31m\]]\$\[\033[00m\] '
    else
        PS1='\[\033[01;32m\][\u@\h\[\033[01;37m\] \W\[\033[01;32m\]]\$\[\033[00m\] '
    fi

    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    alias grep='grep --colour=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --colour=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --colour=auto'
else
    if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]] ; then
        # show root@ when we don't have colors
        PS1='\u@\h \W \$ '
    else
        PS1='\u@\h \w \$ '
    fi
fi

unset use_color safe_term match_lhs sh

alias cp="cp -i"                          # confirm before overwriting something
alias df='df -h'                          # human-readable sizes
alias free='free -m'                      # show sizes in MB
alias np='nano -w PKGBUILD'
alias more=less

xhost +local:root > /dev/null 2>&1

complete -cf sudo

# Bash won't get SIGWINCH if another process is in the foreground.
# Enable checkwinsize so that bash will check the terminal size when
# it regains control.  #65623
# http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/~chet/bash/FAQ (E11)
shopt -s checkwinsize

shopt -s expand_aliases

# export QT_SELECT=4

# Enable history appending instead of overwriting.  #139609
shopt -s histappend

#
# # ex - archive extractor
# # usage: ex <file>
ex ()
{
  if [ -f $1 ] ; then
    case $1 in
      *.tar.bz2)   tar xjf $1   ;;
      *.tar.gz)    tar xzf $1   ;;
      *.bz2)       bunzip2 $1   ;;
      *.rar)       unrar x $1     ;;
      *.gz)        gunzip $1    ;;
      *.tar)       tar xf $1    ;;
      *.tbz2)      tar xjf $1   ;;
      *.tgz)       tar xzf $1   ;;
      *.zip)       unzip $1     ;;
      *.Z)         uncompress $1;;
      *.7z)        7z x $1      ;;
      *)           echo "'$1' cannot be extracted via ex()" ;;
    esac
  else
    echo "'$1' is not a valid file"
  fi
}
```

#### Current *.zshrc* file:

```
# config for the Zoomer Shell

# Enable colors and change prompt:
autoload -U colors && colors
PS1="%B%{$fg[red]%}[%{$fg[yellow]%}%n%{$fg[green]%}@%{$fg[blue]%}%M %{$fg[magenta]%}%~%{$fg[red]%}]%{$reset_color%}$%b "

# History in cache directory:
HISTSIZE=10000
SAVEHIST=10000
HISTFILE=~/.cache/zsh/history

safe_term=${TERM//[^[:alnum:]]/?}   # sanitize TERM
match_lhs=""
[[ -f ~/.dir_colors   ]] && match_lhs="${match_lhs}$(<~/.dir_colors)"
[[ -f /etc/DIR_COLORS ]] && match_lhs="${match_lhs}$(</etc/DIR_COLORS)"
[[ -z ${match_lhs}    ]] \
    && type dircolors >/dev/null \
    && match_lhs=$(dircolors --print-database)
[[ $'\n'${match_lhs} == *$'\n'"TERM "${safe_term}* ]] && use_color=true

if ${use_color} ; then
    # Enable colors for ls, etc.  Prefer ~/.dir_colors #64489
    if type dircolors >/dev/null ; then
        if [[ -f ~/.dir_colors ]] ; then
            eval $(dircolors -b ~/.dir_colors)
        elif [[ -f /etc/DIR_COLORS ]] ; then
            eval $(dircolors -b /etc/DIR_COLORS)
        fi
    fi

    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    alias grep='grep --colour=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --colour=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --colour=auto'
else
    if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]] ; then
        # show root@ when we don't have colors
        PS1='\u@\h \W \$ '
    else
        PS1='\u@\h \w \$ '
    fi
fi

unset use_color safe_term match_lhs sh

alias cp="cp -i"                          # confirm before overwriting something
alias df='df -h'                          # human-readable sizes
alias free='free -m'                      # show sizes in MB
alias np='nano -w PKGBUILD'
alias more=less

xhost +local:root > /dev/null 2>&1


# Basic auto/tab complete:
autoload -U compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select
zmodload zsh/complist
compinit
_comp_options+=(globdots)       # Include hidden files.

# vi mode
bindkey -v
export KEYTIMEOUT=1

# Use vim keys in tab complete menu:
bindkey -M menuselect 'h' vi-backward-char
bindkey -M menuselect 'k' vi-up-line-or-history
bindkey -M menuselect 'l' vi-forward-char
bindkey -M menuselect 'j' vi-down-line-or-history
bindkey -v '^?' backward-delete-char

# Change cursor shape for different vi modes.
function zle-keymap-select {
  if [[ ${KEYMAP} == vicmd ]] ||
     [[ $1 = 'block' ]]; then
    echo -ne '\e[1 q'
  elif [[ ${KEYMAP} == main ]] ||
       [[ ${KEYMAP} == viins ]] ||
       [[ ${KEYMAP} = '' ]] ||
       [[ $1 = 'beam' ]]; then
    echo -ne '\e[5 q'
  fi
}
zle -N zle-keymap-select
zle-line-init() {
    zle -K viins # initiate `vi insert` as keymap (can be removed if `bindkey -V` has been set elsewhere)
    echo -ne "\e[5 q"
}
zle -N zle-line-init
echo -ne '\e[5 q' # Use beam shape cursor on startup.
preexec() { echo -ne '\e[5 q' ;} # Use beam shape cursor for each new prompt.

# Edit line in vim with ctrl-e:
autoload edit-command-line; zle -N edit-command-line
bindkey '^e' edit-command-line

# Load aliases and shortcuts if existent.
[ -f "$HOME/.config/shortcutrc" ] && source "$HOME/.config/shortcutrc"
[ -f "$HOME/.config/aliasrc" ] && source "$HOME/.config/aliasrc"

# Load zsh-syntax-highlighting; should be last.
source /usr/share/zsh/plugins/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh 2>/dev/null

source ~/path/to/fsh/fast-syntax-highlighting.plugin.zsh
```

#### Current *.dir_colors* file:

```
# Configuration file for dircolors, a utility to help you set the
# LS_COLORS environment variable used by GNU ls with the --color option.

# Copyright (C) 1996-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
# Copying and distribution of this file, with or without modification,
# are permitted provided the copyright notice and this notice are preserved.

# The keywords COLOR, OPTIONS, and EIGHTBIT (honored by the
# slackware version of dircolors) are recognized but ignored.

# You can copy this file to .dir_colors in your $HOME directory to override
# the system defaults.

# Below, there should be one TERM entry for each termtype that is colorizable
TERM Eterm
TERM ansi
TERM color-xterm
TERM con132x25
TERM con132x30
TERM con132x43
TERM con132x60
TERM con80x25
TERM con80x28
TERM con80x30
TERM con80x43
TERM con80x50
TERM con80x60
TERM cons25
TERM console
TERM cygwin
TERM dtterm
TERM eterm-color
TERM gnome
TERM gnome-256color
TERM hurd
TERM jfbterm
TERM konsole
TERM kterm
TERM linux
TERM linux-c
TERM mach-color
TERM mach-gnu-color
TERM mlterm
TERM putty
TERM putty-256color
TERM rxvt
TERM rxvt-256color
TERM rxvt-cygwin
TERM rxvt-cygwin-native
TERM rxvt-unicode
TERM rxvt-unicode-256color
TERM rxvt-unicode256
TERM screen
TERM screen-256color
TERM screen-256color-bce
TERM screen-bce
TERM screen-w
TERM screen.Eterm
TERM screen.rxvt
TERM screen.linux
TERM st
TERM st-256color
TERM terminator
TERM vt100
TERM xterm
TERM xterm-16color
TERM xterm-256color
TERM xterm-88color
TERM xterm-color
TERM xterm-debian

# Below are the color init strings for the basic file types. A color init
# string consists of one or more of the following numeric codes:
# Attribute codes:
# 00=none 01=bold 04=underscore 05=blink 07=reverse 08=concealed
# Text color codes:
# 30=black 31=red 32=green 33=yellow 34=blue 35=magenta 36=cyan 37=white
# Background color codes:
# 40=black 41=red 42=green 43=yellow 44=blue 45=magenta 46=cyan 47=white
#NORMAL 00  # no color code at all
#FILE 00    # regular file: use no color at all
RESET 0     # reset to "normal" color
DIR 01;34   # directory
LINK 01;36  # symbolic link.  (If you set this to 'target' instead of a
                # numerical value, the color is as for the file pointed to.)
MULTIHARDLINK 00    # regular file with more than one link
FIFO 40;33  # pipe
SOCK 01;35  # socket
DOOR 01;35  # door
BLK 40;33;01    # block device driver
CHR 40;33;01    # character device driver
ORPHAN 01;05;37;41  # orphaned syminks
MISSING 01;05;37;41 # ... and the files they point to
SETUID 37;41    # file that is setuid (u+s)
SETGID 30;43    # file that is setgid (g+s)
CAPABILITY 30;41    # file with capability
STICKY_OTHER_WRITABLE 30;42 # dir that is sticky and other-writable (+t,o+w)
OTHER_WRITABLE 34;42 # dir that is other-writable (o+w) and not sticky
STICKY 37;44    # dir with the sticky bit set (+t) and not other-writable

# This is for files with execute permission:
EXEC 01;32

# List any file extensions like '.gz' or '.tar' that you would like ls
# to colorize below. Put the extension, a space, and the color init string.
# (and any comments you want to add after a '#')

# If you use DOS-style suffixes, you may want to uncomment the following:
#.cmd 01;32 # executables (bright green)
#.exe 01;32
#.com 01;32
#.btm 01;32
#.bat 01;32
# Or if you want to colorize scripts even if they do not have the
# executable bit actually set.
#.sh  01;32
#.csh 01;32

 # archives or compressed (bright red)
.tar 01;31
.tgz 01;31
.arc 01;31
.arj 01;31
.taz 01;31
.lha 01;31
.lz4 01;31
.lzh 01;31
.lzma 01;31
.tlz 01;31
.txz 01;31
.tzo 01;31
.t7z 01;31
.zip 01;31
.z   01;31
.Z   01;31
.dz  01;31
.gz  01;31
.lrz 01;31
.lz  01;31
.lzo 01;31
.xz  01;31
.bz2 01;31
.bz  01;31
.tbz 01;31
.tbz2 01;31
.tz  01;31
.deb 01;31
.rpm 01;31
.jar 01;31
.war 01;31
.ear 01;31
.sar 01;31
.rar 01;31
.alz 01;31
.ace 01;31
.zoo 01;31
.cpio 01;31
.7z  01;31
.rz  01;31
.cab 01;31

# image formats
.jpg 01;35
.jpeg 01;35
.gif 01;35
.bmp 01;35
.pbm 01;35
.pgm 01;35
.ppm 01;35
.tga 01;35
.xbm 01;35
.xpm 01;35
.tif 01;35
.tiff 01;35
.png 01;35
.svg 01;35
.svgz 01;35
.mng 01;35
.pcx 01;35
.mov 01;35
.mpg 01;35
.mpeg 01;35
.m2v 01;35
.mkv 01;35
.webm 01;35
.ogm 01;35
.mp4 01;35
.m4v 01;35
.mp4v 01;35
.vob 01;35
.qt  01;35
.nuv 01;35
.wmv 01;35
.asf 01;35
.rm  01;35
.rmvb 01;35
.flc 01;35
.avi 01;35
.fli 01;35
.flv 01;35
.gl 01;35
.dl 01;35
.xcf 01;35
.xwd 01;35
.yuv 01;35
.cgm 01;35
.emf 01;35

# http://wiki.xiph.org/index.php/MIME_Types_and_File_Extensions
.axv 01;35
.anx 01;35
.ogv 01;35
.ogx 01;35

# Document files
.pdf 00;32
.ps 00;32
.txt 00;32
.patch 00;32
.diff 00;32
.log 00;32
.tex 00;32
.doc 00;32

# audio formats
.aac 00;36
.au 00;36
.flac 00;36
.m4a 00;36
.mid 00;36
.midi 00;36
.mka 00;36
.mp3 00;36
.mpc 00;36
.ogg 00;36
.ra 00;36
.wav 00;36

# http://wiki.xiph.org/index.php/MIME_Types_and_File_Extensions
.axa 00;36
.oga 00;36
.spx 00;36
.xspf 00;36
```

Comment: Compare the value of `PS1` in both your `bash` and your `zsh` sessions, then modify your `.bashrc` accordingly.  (`echo $PS1`)

Comment: Thanks, but I've already attempted to replace the PS1 in the .bashrc file with the one from .zshrc, and it had no effect. But to be honest, I don't really care about the .bashrc prompt. I mainly would like to know how to add the timestamp I referenced above to both prompts. I am mainly struggling with where to add the "\D{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}", and making sure to integrate with proper syntax

Comment: I would add the extra format at the beginning of `PS1`, see how it looks, and decide whether you want to relocate it further down in the string.  Strings patterns like `\[\033[01;31m\]`, the characters between `\[` and \\] are effectively ANSI control sequences used to set colors, etc.

Comment: Have you tried using an [online PS1 wizard](http://bashrcgenerator.com/)?

Answer (score 7):

I added:

#### In file *.bashrc*:

```
\D{%F} \t
```

to the front of the `PS1=` string. This gave me the full format date as well as the time.

#### In file *.zshrc*

```
20%D %*
```

to the front of the `PS1=` string. %D only gives yy-mm-dd format, so I added 20 to the front, to unify things across both prompts. I also just trial-n-error grinded through trying to match my colors from my zsh prompt to the bash prompt.. Finally I arrived at what I wanted:

[Trial & Error Progression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrAhB.jpg)

#### Current *.bashrc* PS1:

```
PS1="\D{%F} \t \[\033[01;31m\][\[\033[01;33m\]\u\[\033[01;32m\]@\[\033[01;34m\]\h\[\033[01;37m\] \W\[\033[01;31m\]]\[\033[01;32m\]$\[\033[0m\] "
```

#### Current *.zshrc* PS1

```
PS1="20%D %*%B%{$fg[red]%}[%{$fg[yellow]%}%n%{$fg[green]%}@%{$fg[blue]%}%M %{$fg[magenta]%}%~%{$fg[red]%}]%{$reset_color%}$%b "
```

Also *during* my trials, I ran into an issue where I was getting weird line-wrapping behaviors on the bash prompt, where text beyond a certain amount of characters would wrap onto the same line and obscure my prompt.

This was resolved by escaping from all the color additions correctly...

Example:

[\033[01;31m]

#### Current Bash prompt:

[Colored Prompt with Timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CnHN.jpg)

Comment: can you link to a resource explaining the formatting language of zsh? It is very hard to edit otherwise.

Comment: The OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 2 years ago"*